# Trying to use javascript to add unique class when radio button checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, radio-button, checked

I'm trying to use javascript to change the background color of the radio label when it is checked. Each radio button will apply a different class or color. I need to use java because of a css conflict with a plugin. Also need the radio value field for dynamic purposes, so can't use that field to add class.

Here's where I'm at:

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $('#emailGroup1').change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      $(this).parent().addClass('Good');
    } else {
      $(this).parent().removeClass('Good');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="confirmGroup">
  <form>
    <label id="emailGroup">
      <input type="radio" name="emailConfirm" id="emailGroup1" value="Pending" checked>
      Pending
    </label>
    <label id="emailGroup">
      <input type="radio" name="emailConfirm" id="emailGroup2" value="Good">
      Good
    </label>
    <label id="emailGroup">
      <input type="radio" name="emailConfirm" id="emailGroup3" value="Bad">
      Bad
    </label>
  </form>
</div>
```

I'd like to have the javascript read the default checked radio button and apply that class when page loads. Then when user selects different radio button, class is removed from default checked and applied to selection.

Comment: 1. There is no `#emailGroup1` element 2. You've repeated the same `id` throughout your code which is invalid. Use classes instead 3. 'a CSS conflict' is no reason to use JS - you can still use CSS if you set your rules with high enough specificity.

Comment: Sorry... let me edit code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should listen to radio buttons not labels and i saw that you're setting a not unique ID to label's that it's wrong, html tag's Id should have a unique value.

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $('input[name=emailConfirm]').change(function() {
    $('.emailGroup').removeClass('Good')
    $(this).parent().addClass('Good');
  });
});
```

```css
.Good {
  background: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="confirmGroup">
  <form>
    <label class="emailGroup Good">
    <input type="radio" name="emailConfirm" value="Pending" checked>
    Pending</label>
    <label class="emailGroup">
    <input type="radio" name="emailConfirm" value="Good">
    Good</label>
    <label class="emailGroup">
    <input type="radio" name="emailConfirm" value="Bad">
    Bad</label>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is due to your duplicate use of `id` attributes, which is invalid. you can instead use common `class` attributes to target your elements and then apply the `good` class as needed. Try this:

```js
$('.email').change(function() {
  $('.emailGroup.good').removeClass('good');
  $(this).closest('.emailGroup').addClass('good');
});
```

```css
.good { background-color: #0D0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="confirmGroup">
  <form>
    <label class="emailGroup">
      <input type="radio" name="emailConfirm" id="emailGroup1" value="Pending" checked="true" class="email">
      Pending
    </label>
    <label class="emailGroup">
      <input type="radio" name="emailConfirm" id="emailGroup2" value="Good" class="email">
      Good
    </label>
    <label class="emailGroup">
      <input type="radio" name="emailConfirm" id="emailGroup3" value="Bad" class="email">
      Bad
    </label>
  </form>
</div>
```

Also note that this can be achieved using CSS alone by a slight amendment of your HTML:

```css
.email:checked + label { 
  background-color: #0C0;
}
```

```html
<div id="confirmGroup">
  <form>
    <input type="radio" name="emailConfirm" id="emailGroup1" value="Pending" checked="true" class="email">
    <label class="emailGroup" for="emailGroup1">
      Pending
    </label>

    <input type="radio" name="emailConfirm" id="emailGroup2" value="Good" class="email">
    <label class="emailGroup" for="emailGroup2">
      Good
    </label>

    <input type="radio" name="emailConfirm" id="emailGroup3" value="Bad" class="email">
    <label class="emailGroup" for="emailGroup3">
      Bad
    </label>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome!! The CSS solution was perfect.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $("input[type=radio]:checked").parent().css('background','yellow');
  $('input[name=emailConfirm]').change(function() {
    $('.emailGroup').css('background','none');
    if($(this).val() == "Good"){
      $(this).parent().css('background','green');
    }
    if($(this).val() == "Bad"){
      $(this).parent().css('background','red');
    }
    if($(this).val() == "Pending"){
      $(this).parent().css('background','yellow');
    }
    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="confirmGroup">
  <form>
    <label class="emailGroup">
    <input type="radio" name="emailConfirm" value="Pending" checked>
    Pending</label>
    <label class="emailGroup">
    <input type="radio" name="emailConfirm" value="Good">
    Good</label>
    <label class="emailGroup">
    <input type="radio" name="emailConfirm" value="Bad">
    Bad</label>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Very nice!! Thank you.

Comment: Always Welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
  $('.emailGroup input').change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      $(this).parent().parent().addClass('Good');
    } else {
      $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('Good');
    }
  });
```

```css
#confirmGroup{
  color: red;
}
.Good {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="confirmGroup">
  <form>
    <label class="emailGroup">
      <input type="radio" name="emailConfirm" value="Pending" >
      Pending
    </label>
    <label class="emailGroup">
      <input type="radio" name="emailConfirm" value="Good">
      Good
    </label>
    <label class="emailGroup">
      <input type="radio" name="emailConfirm" value="Bad">
      Bad
    </label>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('input[type=radio]')` selector to bind events to all radio inputs. And Use `.trigger()` method to call radio inputs `change` event on page load.

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $('input[type=radio]').change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $(this).parent().addClass('Good');
    } else {
      $(this).parent().removeClass('Good');
    }
  }).trigger('change');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="confirmGroup">
  <form>
    <label id="emailGroup">
      <input type="radio" name="emailConfirm" id="emailGroup1" value="Pending" checked>
      Pending
    </label>
    <label id="emailGroup">
      <input type="radio" name="emailConfirm" id="emailGroup2" value="Good">
      Good
    </label>
    <label id="emailGroup">
      <input type="radio" name="emailConfirm" id="emailGroup3" value="Bad">
      Bad
    </label>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: There are labels having identical `id` attribute in your code.